# Visual Studio 2015 breakpoint settings are missing from Fonts and Colors menu

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

When debugging my code in C# I noticed that the debugger does not highlight the code either red for breakpoint line or yellow for current execution line. I've looked at my work computer and my home computer (where the problem is) and I've noticed that any "Breakpoint" settings are completely missing out of the Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors menu. Compared to my work computer where there's multiple Breakpoint options. Did I miss a package at install time?

Comment: Maybe you could share a screen shot about the real differences for them, for this debugging issue, please create a simple console app, debug it again, if it still has this issue, we would think about the VS Environment, please reset your VS settings firstly, if still no help, repair your VS would be better.

Comment: Would you please share the latest information about this issue? Do you use the latest VS2015 with update 3?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried to repair VS2015 professional with no change. I completely uninstalled VS2015 and installed VS2015 Community and it still has the same issue. The Breakpoint Fonts and Colors are just missing from the menu.

Work - 
https://imgur.com/a/FSMEE
Home - https://imgur.com/a/akDsP

Comment: Update 2: I also tried to export my settings from my work computer and import them at my home computer with no avail.

Comment: I view one VS2015 community version in my side, it really has breakpoint settings there, so I feel that it would be the Environment issue. (1) Please custom the setup during you install the VS, not use the default one.(2) Just compare the installed product and version number under Hlep->About Visual studio in your two different machines.(3) Do you install certain extension tools or add-ins? Maybe you installed certain custom theme color extension tool or others in your side, please disable it. (4) Not import other VS settings, just reset it in your side like use the default C# language setting

Comment: I did do a custom install and installed more packages...maybe you're right. Maybe one overrode the Environment variable for the Debugging fonts and colors. Let me uninstall and install fresh but leave everything default.

Comment: Please also run command line devenv.exe /setup and devenv /resetuserdata view the result. Or just open your VS in safe mode: deven.exe /SafeMode, at least, we could know that whether it is related to the extension tools or add-ins. If you get any update, share it here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed the problem. What had happened was I had a few previous versions of Visual Studio that I installed before 2015 and uninstalling these previous versions left "stale MSI's" hanging around my C:\ drive and other junk in the Registry. I found this tool from the [VisualStudio](http://www.visualstudio.com) website that cleaned them up. [Visual Studio Installation clean up tool.](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases)
 I reinstalled visual studio and it's fully functional now.

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue. Thanks for you sharing:)